# Access specific line Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am defining a Datatable this way:

```
var dat_one = $('#dat_one').DataTable({
  select: {
    style: 'single'
  },
  responsive: true,
});
```

I would like to access a specific line of my datatable. I want to color a line that contains a specific string. (Example: Line that contains 'Ashton Cox' as column 1 and 'San Francisco' as column 3  [image]

I tried to color a selected line with this code :

```
$(".selected").css('background-color', '#ccffcc');
```

But doesn't works if my line is not selected.

Comment: Why not use pure CSS  instead `.selected{background-color:newColor}`

Comment: Can you show HTML code?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I want to access an UNSELECTED line, that's my point

Answer (score 1):

Try using **rowCallback**. There you can change row attributes with value checking.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    if ( data.grade == "A" ) {
      $('td:eq(4)', row).html( '<b>A</b>' );
    }
  }
} );
```

This is [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback). Note the function has many other parameters you can use.

```
rowCallback( row, data, displayNum, displayIndex, dataIndex )
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()), this is an alternative to **Aruna Perera**:

```
// var table = $('#dat_one').DataTable()  ;
dat_one.rows().eq(0).each( function ( index ) {
    var row = table.row( index );

    var data = row.data();

    var column0value = data[0];
    if(column0value == "Airi Satou"){
      $(row.node()).css("background-color", "yellow")
    }
    // ... do something with data(), or row.node(), etc
} );
```